# Rigged model wrong in object mode when I import it

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects

This is what my rigged model looks like in *Object Mode* when I import it:

[image]

But is correct in *Edit Mode*:

[image: edit mode is correct, but object mode isn't]

How to fix this?

Comment: It's probably a pose. Have you tried to clear it? (Select armature, switch to pose mode, select all bones, select menu *Pose > Clear Transform > All*)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.